# php header cannot redirect

Tags: php, redirect, header

I have implemented a simple signup page,which after the user has signed up must re-direct them to the thank you page, here is my code and it returns a blank page

'
save.php
'

```
   if($mail->Send()) {}

    unset($_SESSION['GENRE_REQUEST']);

    }
    header('Location:thanku.php');
        exit();
    }
    else
        {
        header('Location:thanku.php');
        exit();
        } '
```

---

thanku.php

```
 <tr>
       <td align="center" valign="top"><b>Thank You for Registering With us.</b> <br />
        <br />please activate your profile by clicking on the activation link sent to your email address.<br/>
       </td>
  </tr> 'a
                      '
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting. And tell the error.

Comment: Two things:  Make sure your `save.php` program is executing the line that your redirect takes place on by placing a `die('test')` just before the `header()` call.  Then, make sure your `thanku.php` page is getting called by clearing it of all contents and putting `test` text in it.  That way, you will know where the error is occurring.

Comment: according to the post you posted you got a `}` to much in the first line remove the last one

Comment: if I ever saw a page named "thanku", I would probably leave immediately.

Comment: sorry, what is this?    } '  is it a typo?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Header redirect not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423860/php-header-redirect-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
if($mail->Send()) {
    header('Location:thanku.php');
    exit();
}else{
    echo "Oops! there was some error in sending the mail";
}
```

In thanku.php page,

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    $_SESSION = array();

    echo "Thanks message";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see more of your code. Also, if your header("Location:somenewpage.php") call is failing, php should be emitting some sort of error. Do you have display_errors turned on in your php settings (at least for your dev environment)? That will help you get a sense for what is going wrong with your script.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this

```
if($mail->Send()) {
   session_destroy();
   header('Location:thanku.php');
}
else
{
  header('Location:thanku.php');
}
```

Comment: unset() will not completely destroy the session.

Comment: else { echo "Error sending mail";}