# header working on localhost but not working on a live server

Tags: php, mysql

wonder if anyone could help.
my problem is that the site works on localhost but when I ftp it to a live server the header() doesn't redirect them to (in this case) a thank you page, the data how ever is recorded in the database.

PHP code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $connect_error = 'Sorry, Connection problems.';
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password') or die($connect_error);
    mysql_select_db('email_logs') or die($connect_error);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO client_data (name, email) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) . "')";
    mysql_query($sql);
    mysql_close();
    header("Location: thankyou.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: you forgot to upload thankyou.php? Or it's not where you think it is?

Comment: Did you get any error instead?

Comment: Offtopic: don't use mysql_* functions, it's deprecated, use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: The thank you page is uploaded, if I type the url of the website in the bar and include /thankyou.php it shows that thank you page.

Comment: and nope no errors what so ever..

Comment: Do you get errors in other pages? Maybe displaying errors is disabled in your server.

Comment: What are the versions of PHP (both local and remote)?

Comment: error messages are enables on the server, and they are running version 5.3. my local server is through xammp, how would I check the php version? sorry a little new to this.

Comment: nevermind, fount it. Im running version 5.4.16

Comment: Try replacing header() for echo() or something, it's the most primitive form of debugging. Also, if you found solved issue, please close your question and/or answer itself properly!

Comment: thanks everyone okay so ive includes the ob_start("ob_gzhandler"); at the top aswell as the error reporting line, and its returned this error "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/kia03/public_html/index.php:2) in /home/kia03/public_html/index.php on line 30"

Comment: [check out this post regarding php headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423860/php-header-redirect-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

your code is fine...if u want u can try defining relative paths like...`/path/to/thankyou.php`..watch what happens..if it still not running..then check by `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and tell us what the actual error

Answer (score 1):

This may help you.

```
ob_start();
```

You can add this at the top of `thankyou.php`

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the top of the script

```
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
```

Comment: read the article and checked for everything that was listed in it, still nothing works... Is there a way to instead of redirecting rather have the form disappear and a thank you message replace it?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below piece of code

fileName:**fix.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();
...
header('Location: page1.php');
...
ob_end_flush();
?>
```