# unable to send user to other page php

Tags: php

i have a code that fetch a movie trailler and create a youtube url. everything is work ok except when it's time to open it in the browser, here the code

```
if (isset($_POST['link'])){
    $arr1 = $_POST['link']; 
    $movieName = str_replace(' ', '+', $arr1[0]);
    $movieYear = $arr1[1];
    $page = file_get_contents('http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query='.$movieName.'+'.$movieYear.'+trailer&aq=1&hl=en');
    if($page){
         if(preg_match('~<a .*?href="/watch\?v=(.*?)".*?</div>~s', $page, $matches))
             $youtubelink = "http://www.youtube.com/v/" . $matches[1];
             header("Location: '".$youtubelink."'");
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<b>Trailler not found</b>";
        }
}
```

When i press the button, it does not send me to the youtube link, i know that the link is good cause when i erase the header code and echo the $youtubelink, it is the good address.

Thanks

Edit:
I end up with this:

```
echo "<script>window.location = '$youtubelink'</script>";
```

Comment: Remove the single quotes from your `header`.

Answer (score 4):

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

Those single quotes are messing you up.

Comment: It's probably me the problem but when i change the messed header with the one you give me to test it, it does not send me to the www.example.com.

Comment: Does your `preg_match` actually match anything?

Comment: Yes like i say before if i change the header line with echo $youtubelink, it print the url

Comment: can you print out `$youtubelink` right before the redirect and show us what it looks like? Just to be sure it works as expected?

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to this, i post the code in my question in the edit section, Hope that it's that way to do it if not, sorry

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423860/php-header-redirect-not-working

Try the suggestions there