# Header doesn't seem to work on web server

Tags: php, session, header

```
    <?php
  session_start();
  if (empty($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $_SESSION['errMsg'] = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <strong>Post:</strong> You must be logged in `enter code here`in order to post.
    </div>';
    header('Location: ../../index.php');
    exit;
  }
?>
```

It just doesn't redirect me to index.php, which is in the proper place, even though the session doesn't exist.

Comment: what have you tried? Did you checked your log-files? What happens, when you remove the "exit"?

Comment: Without the exit; it still doesn't seem to work. I will check if it works without GZip now, although this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yes, exit is mandatory on redirect. use a FQDN (means an absolute url like http://example.com/index.php) in your header function.

Comment: Silly question, but does `$_SESSION['id']` have a value? i.e. does your code get to the `header`?

Comment: It has a value when you're logged in. Whenever you're not logged in it doesn't, that's why it checks if it's empty or not. If it's empty, you're not allowed to go to the page, so you'll be redirected to the index page

Comment: So `$_SESSION['id']` IS empty? Can you echo/print something before/after the `header`?

Comment: yes, that works just fine

Comment: have you checked this out? http://stackoverflow.com/a/24928578/715105

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Header redirect not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423860/php-header-redirect-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I understand your redirect problem

From the above code

```
header('Location: ../../index.php');
```

Your project is example.com/testfolder/view.php

Make change the Path and If your index.php is in previous folder means simply add

```
../index.php
```

Likewise monitor and set your path in the header.

Comment: It still doesn't work. On my localhost it DOES work, but it just doesn't work on Strato (Web domain host)

Comment: I think there is some problem in your code or your hosting. Ok just try it through Javascript  <script> window.location = "http://www.example.com"; </script>

Answer (score 0):

Just Try :-

```
header('Location: http://myhost.com/mypage.php');
```

[PHP header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: First open your index.php page in url , then add header like shown  above .

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
  session_start();
  if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    header('Location: ../../index.php');
    exit;
  }
?>
```

I fixed it, I don't know how, but it works now. This is the code I use now

Comment: please read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191626/isset-and-empty-what-to-use   then you will understand why does it work now