# PHP redirecting not showing content of the page redirected to

Tags: php, redirect

Page1.php code;

```
...
header('Location: editt.php?msg=landing&msisdn='.$msisdn);
...
```

page2.php code;

```
$msisdn = $_GET['msisdn'];
$msg = $_GET['msg'];
echo 'Page 2 Content '.$msisdn;
```

Comment: Presumably `page2.php` is `editt.php`?

Comment: Sorry for asking the obvious but... Does the page show display properly if loaded directly from the location bar?

Comment: is it page2 or editt ?!

Comment: page2 is called 'editt.php' (with 2 't's)?

Comment: Page2 is editt.php

Comment: if you were to enter `editt.php?msg=landing&msisdn=6` into your browser, does it display `"Page 2 Content 6"`? @Givelasdougmore

Comment: the content of page2 it only shows after i refresh the page after it redirect to the page

Comment: yes it does @blackandorangecat

Comment: yes it does load properly if i load it from the address bar. @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: Have you read through the specs? http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php Make sure to exit after calling header.

Comment: I still have the same problem even if i placed the exit() after the header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not using header as container of your data :

```
header('msg: msgValue');
header('msisdn: msisdnValue');
header('Location: editt.php');
```

in edit.php

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();

foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
    echo "$header: $value <br />\n";
}
```

Comment: I am still having the same problem. the way i have done it, it works in the other pages. When i do the same thing on page1 it is not working

Comment: i think you have another problem somewhere please past your full code

Answer (score 1):

The piece of code you posted works , maybe in the rest of your code there is some html output before `header( )` , this can be also in some of included files if there is some .

UPDATE :

Some useful answers about the same issue could be found here :

[php-header-redirect-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423860/php-header-redirect-not-working)

Comment: No, there is no html output, i only have an API call before it

Comment: There is some useful answers  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423860/php-header-redirect-not-working) , it may help .

Comment: maybe showing more code will help others to understand the problem .