# Wordpress 4.9.1 doesnt redirect after creating, installing, updating or deleting something

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a fresh install of Wordpress 4.9.1 on a MAMP server.

I have Advanced custom fields, Contact form 7 and Easy logo installed.

I'm building my own theme, which have been working fine until today.

My problem is that when I delete/update a page Wordpress executes it, but then it doesnt redirect me back to `Dashboard/Pages`.

It stays on a blank white page.

If I remove all the excess URL and load `localhost:8888/wp-admin` I'm where I should be, page deleted/updated.

How can I solve this issue?

What can be causing Wordpress to not redirect after a Page delete/update?

I get three similar error messages:
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-includes/functions.php:4146`) in `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-admin/includes/misc.php` on line 1114

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-includes/functions.php:4146`) in `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-admin/post.php` on line 198

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-includes/functions.php:4146`) in `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-includes/pluggable.php` on line 1216

Comment: what errors did you get? provide error logs

Comment: This is one of three similar ones: 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-includes/functions.php:4146`) in `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-admin/includes/misc.php` on line 1114

Comment: update your question with this information(errors)

Comment: The two latter ones disappear when I deactivate Advanced custom fields.

Comment: Okay, so after some troubleshooting I have been able to get rid of the two latter errors. One still remain, which is the first one.

Comment: Probaby related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788290/error-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423860/php-header-redirect-not-working)?

Comment: @HassiaBiker Not related. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after some troubleshooting:

There were some errors in my functions.php.
Firstly, I had a function with starting and closing php-tags, which was wrong. The rest of the issues were solved when I had an error on line 46 (last line in my functions.php) which when I deleted it, I just thought it was two extra lines. But there were probably a space that was trying to be outputted. With those lines gone; problem solved!